# Find first number in column that is GTE to number in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell somewhere else (`cell X`) with a number in it and I want to write a formula that will look in the `TOTAL` column and return the first cell that is greater than or equal to `cell X`.

If possible, I'd like to take it a step further and return the respective month of the cell in the `TOTAL` column.

```
MONTH    TOTAL           CONTRIBUTION
April    $ 1,000.00      $ 1,000.00 
May      $ 3,000.00      $ 2,000.00 
June     $ 4,000.00      $ 1,000.00 
July     $ 7,000.00      $ 3,000.00 
August   $ 7,500.00      $ 500.00
```

Comment: What do you mean by GTE?

Comment: Sorry, greater than or equal to

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to sort the total column the other way and then use these formulas to return the amount and month, respectively.

`=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(D2,B1:B6,-1))`
`=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(D2,B1:B6,-1))`

[image]

Comment: Sweet thanks! okay, I took it one step further with - `=INDEX($C$2:$C$53,MATCH(TRUE,$C$2:$C$53>=I44,0))`

The above formula gives me the first cell in the `TOTAL` column that is equal to `cell X`. Now to make it give the month

Comment: It will return from the range in the first input to the index formula. So change the first $c$2 :$c$53 to column a instead (or wherever your months are)

Comment: Ah, I got it!

First formula: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$53,MATCH(TRUE,$C$2:$C$53>=I44,0))`
As noted above, looks in `cell x`, in this case `I44`, to find the first value in the `TOTAL` column and returns that.

Second Formula:  `=INDEX($B$2:$B$53,MATCH(J45,$C$2:$C$53,0))`
Indexes the `MONTH` column and matches it to the value provided from the first formula in the `TOTAL` Column.

Answer (score 0):

Huge kudos to @Hooded 0ne for getting me 99% of the way. This is nice, because lets say the expected month is Jan 2022 but contributions wind up being higher than expected it automatically adjusts to a sooner month. I <3 Excel

**Nearest Month:**: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$53,MATCH(H2,$B$2:$B$53,0))`

**First Cell to Match**  `=INDEX($B$2:$B$53,MATCH(TRUE,$B$2:$B$53>=F2,0))`

I think the only thing that would be nicer is if there is a way to combine `H2` and `G2`

**EDIT:** Well this is nice... final Formula combined into one cell:
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$53,MATCH(INDEX($B$2:$B$53,MATCH(TRUE,$B$2:$B$53>=F2,0)),$B$2:$B$53,0))`

*** Can't directly post image due to lack of reputation... :shrug_emoji:

[First try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbO8.png)

[The Winning Forumla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXZDn.png)

Comment: I was replicating this in another sheet and realized this works on strings but it won't work if it is a date formatted cell. ie, the `MONTH` column displays `May 2020` but in reality it is `5/1/2020` it somehow breaks the formula.

Fixed it by just changing the format to `plain text`

Answer (score 0):

### First Greater Value in Column

The following two are not array formulas:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$2:$B$6>$E$2,0),))
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$2:$B$6>$E$2,0),))
```

I'm using Excel 2019 so I need to enter the following array formulas with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. 365 users probably do not have to.

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH(TRUE,$B$2:$B$6>$E$2,0))
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(TRUE,$B$2:$B$6>$E$2,0))
```